# Read only one Tag from MP4 Metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, itunes, mp3, metadata

On my Desktop PC with Ubuntu i use gpodder for Dowloading my Podcasts. The Dwnloads are renamed automatically. After that i re-encode the files into mp3 and use eyeD3 to set the file name as title tag. Now i want to use a command line downloader for pocasts and the best i've found is "podget". But podget can't rename the files (the title is something like 'episode01.m4a') and so i can't write a useful text the mp3 title tag when i re-encode the files.

eyeD3 can't read the iTunes-Tags from the m4a (mp4) files, but ffmpeg can. But ffmpeg is writting ALL metadata into a file. is there a way to only write the title tag into a text file so that i can write the title tag with eyed3?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffprobe to dump just the title into a text file e.g.

```
ffprobe in.mp3 -show_entries format_tags=title -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 > title.txt
```

title.txt will have just the title terminated with a newline.